# SVG won't scale correctly

Tags: javascript, css, svg

I know this question has been asked before but the accepted solution does not seem to be working in this case.

I have an svg that I need to scale to be 20*20px. When I try and scale it as I do with all my other svgs, by wrapping a parent div with width and height declarations in the associated css, the svg doesn't render well: The circle is ragged around the edge: https://jsfiddle.net/gt7f4unq/

I've tried to change the view box properties to be `0 0 20 20`, but then the svg image disappears. I've also tried to change the first two properties of the viewbox to various different values but this also does not seem to work.

Is there any way to scale this svg correctly?

Comment: Why dont you use the `width` and `height` attributes of the `svg` itself? The `viewBox` determines which part of the `svg` you see. If it is ragged (does that mean cut of?) you would have to enlarge it, like `-1 -1 513 513`

Comment: Looks fine to me. `viewbox` doesn't scale anything, it instead, describes a render bounding box in draw coordinates.

Comment: I don't see the ragged edges but you may try to use the [shape-rendering](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/shape-rendering) attribute to solve this problem

Comment: Ah ok, one my main screen it's ragged around the edges, but on my retina macbook screen it's fine. This might explain why some of you see it as rendering ok.

Answer (score 0):

It is already having 20x20 px.
Please clarify if you need something else:

```css
div {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512"><path d="M256 48a208 208 0 1 1 0 416 208 208 0 1 1 0-416zm0 464A256 256 0 1 0 256 0a256 256 0 1 0 0 512zM232 368h48V344 280h64 24V232H344 280V168 144H232v24 64H168 144v48h24 64v64 24z"/></svg>
</div>
```